# ¿Cómo implementar item assignment en tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
@tf.function
def segmenting(ds, seg, train_count):
  new_ds = {'train': [], 'enrollment': [], 'test': []}
  for name, audio, label in ds:
    for sel_ds, sub_ds in enumerate(new_ds.items()):
      if train_count[sel_ds, name, label]<seg[sel_ds]:
        train_count[sel_ds, name, label] = train_count[sel_ds, name, label] + 1
        sub_ds[1].append({'name': name, 'audio': audio, 'label': label})
        break
  return new_ds['train'], new_ds['enrollment'],new_ds['test']

train, enrollment, test = segmenting(ds1, [20,15,15], np.zeros((3,5,10)))
```

donde el argumento ds es un objeto devuelto por la función:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()
```

y cada elemento dentro del dataset posee la siguiente estructura:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>, 
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1525,), dtype=float32, numpy= array([ 0.,...,-0.015625 ],dtype=float32)>, 
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=2>)
```

El problema es que cuando comento la línea:

```
@tf.function
```

y ejecuto el código no obtengo ningún error. Al contrario de cuando descomento esta misma línea y dejo que la función se ejecute en un grafo de tensorflow(tengo entendido que eso es lo que pasa cuando se agrega @tf.function en la definición de una función) que me devuelve un error de item assignment:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-86075493ae6c> in <module>()
     12 
     13 tc = np.zeros((3,5,10))
---> 14 train, enrollment, test = segmenting(ds1, [20,15,15], tc)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-45-86075493ae6c>:8 segmenting  *
        train_count[sel_ds, name, label] = train_count[sel_ds, name, label] + 1

    TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

Quisiera saber como esquivar este problema para poder ejecutar la función en un grafo de tensorflow, o sea, con la línea @tf.function descomentada.

Saludos y Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: es por que `Tensor` no soporta o no tiene definido un `setitem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Introducción

La función `tf.funtion` que usas como decorador, lo que hace es transformar toda tu función a un grafo de `Tensorflow` lo que significa, que **todas tus operaciones que ejecutes, serán traducidas a `Tensorflow`**.

¿Qué sucederá al realizar operaciones que no están implementadas por `Tensorflow`?

1. Que `@tf.function` manejará los errores pudiendo hacer que tus operaciones funciones
2. Que los desarrolladores de `Tensorflow` no hayan implementado esas operaciones ni resolución de errores y tu código falle.

En este caso a ti te está pasando la segunda opción, puedo replicar tu error de la siguiente forma:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable([[1,2],
                 [3,4]])

a[0][1] = 9
```

**Salida:** `TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment`

Este error nos dice, que cuando se crea un `tf.Tensor`, estos no permiten la asignación. (la única excepción es con el método `.assign()` y está muy restringido).

### 2. Tu error

Esto es lo que está sucediendo en tu código, `tf.function` transforma tu variable `train_counts` a un `tf.Tensor` y luego se realiza la siguiente asignación:
`train_count[sel_ds, name, label] = train_count[sel_ds, name, label] + 1`. Lo cual como hemos visto, no es posible y por tanto te lanza el error.

### 3. Soluciones

Las soluciones posibles son dos:

1. Quitar el decorador `@tf.function` para que la función se ejecute como una función de Python normal y corriente, fuera del grafo de `Tensorflow`
2. Modificar tu función, para que no se realicen asignaciones dentro de ella.

### Bonus extra

`tf.function` suele funcionar muy bien con pequeñas operaciones, pero con operaciones grandes y con distintos tipos, no suele dar ninguna ventaja en velocidad de ejecución, puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function)

> Functions can be faster than eager code, especially for graphs with many small ops. But for graphs with a few expensive ops (like convolutions), you may not see much speedup.

En resumen `tf.function` esta creado para incluir operaciones realizadas con `Tensorflow` en el grafo, mejorando la eficiencia y la velocidad. **No para ponerlo con cualquier operacion de Python**. Un ejemplo de su buen uso sería:

```
@tf.function  # The decorator converts `add` into a `Function`.
def add(a, b):
  return a + b

add(tf.ones([3,3]), tf.ones([3,3]))
```

Otro ejemplo con operaciones más complejas, como puede ser la optimización:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def train_step(w, x, y, optimizer):
   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
       L = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(w*x - y))
   gradients = tape.gradient(L, [w])
   optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [w]))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto!!! Una respuesta muy completa y útil. Gracias por tu tiempo. Saludos!!!